# Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: android, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to retrieve data from database n use

`Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);`

to get values, but it shows error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.rana.sahaj.myyu, PID: 13179
                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.rana.sahaj.myyu.profile.Profile$2.onDataChange(Profile.java:158)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here's the code

```
 DatabaseReference profileRef=mFirebaseRef.child(EEmail);
    profileRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    -->     Map<String, String> map = (Map<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UserInActivity);
            EmailView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailUser);

            PhotoUrl = map.get("picurl");
             emmaill=map.get("userEmail");

            UserNam = map.get("userNAME");

            name.setText(UserNam);
            EmailView.setText(emmaill);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

n there is no problem with key n values in database.
used the solution but not working

Comment: None of the answers on this page worked. This answer is the only one that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711195/4833705

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The error points out correctly where you are going wrong

```
 Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

Map class uses parameter to **define the types of Key and Object** where as you don't give them and simply use `Map.class` which fails.

Try the below code - since Key are always string and we can have any type of Object for them

```
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Comment: can you update your question with the new code you used ?

Comment: use `getValue()` you are still doing `getValue(Map.class);`

Comment: See my correct answer down below. as no solution here worked for me

Comment: getting this error now java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Answer (score 34):

To introduce the `GenericTypeIndicator`, you can change this line:

```
Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

in to this:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {};
Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator );
```

This should work well in your case. Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: `Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` should have worked. But in any case, I have updated the answer to show how to use `GenericTypeIndicator` - you can give this one a try - I hope someone can also find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this worked whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: getting this error now  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.Stri

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and solved it by handling the Object instead trying to have Firebase cast it.

```
Map <String, String> map = (Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

did it for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Nice solution!

Comment: Thank you !! Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `getCheldrin` as follows

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshotNode: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    map.put(snapshotNode.getKey(), snapshotNode.getValue(YOUR_CLASS_TYPE.class));
}
```

Replace the `YOUR_CLASS_TYPE` with the class type you expecting. notice that this class must have an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Chage

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

by this

```
Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

Comment: This answer duplicates content from an existing highly rated answer. Please ensure your answers add something more to the post. See [answer] for more guidance.