# Getting an error with DataSnapshot with fire base on change and storing into a map

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the error I'm getting. I'm following this one tutorial and it throws no errors:

[image: The tutorial screenshot]

I want to store the data off my Firebase database in an easy was to read.

Error message:

```
"Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.Map' to 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>' less... (⌘F1)
```

Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler. For example:

```
 void f(HashMap map) {
    map.put("key", "value");
  }
```

Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details."

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 Map <String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 Log.i("error", "error");
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>)dataSnapShot.getValue(Map.class);
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error `Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead`

Comment: found and answer on here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688031/class-java-util-map-has-generic-type-parameters-please-use-generictypeindicator `