# Android - Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know there's a lot of similar questions like mine, but I've read and tried everything but still unable to solve this issue. What I am trying to achieve is to populate my listview with the data from the firebase. Im following a tutorial on youtube but Ive added some stuff, timestamp in particular. The error is in my for loop and says :

> Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

This is my database looks like :

[image: My Database]

My Notes.java

```
    public class Notes {
String noteId;
String noteCategory;
String note;
String rating;
public Map timeStamp;

public Notes(){

}

public Notes(String noteId, String noteCategory, String note, String rating, Map timeStamp) {
    this.noteId = noteId;
    this.noteCategory = noteCategory;
    this.note = note;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}


public String getNoteId() {
    return noteId;
}

public String getNoteCategory() {
    return noteCategory;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public Map<String,String> getTimeStamp() { return timeStamp;}
}
```

And below is my  NoteList.java

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseNotes.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            notesList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot noteSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Notes notes = noteSnapshot.getValue(Notes.class);
                notesList.add(notes);

            }

            NoteList adapter = new NoteList(MyNotes.this, notesList);
            listViewNotes.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

EDIT : Okay, Ive tried the suggested answer, and after I logged the map it shows my data on the console. However, how do I iterate my map into the listview ?

> ```
> Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688031/class-java-util-map-has-generic-type-parameters-please-use-generictypeindicator)

Comment: The member `timeStamp` is of type `Map`, but it does not indicate of which types the keys and values are. It should be something like `Map<String, String>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688031/class-java-util-map-has-generic-type-parameters-please-use-generictypeindicator

Comment: Yes Ive been through the threads and tried everything. It doesnt work. @NileshRathod

Comment: Doesnt work for my case :( @QandilTariq

Comment: I think im already using Map<String, String> , look at my getter @0xDEADC0DE

Comment: @Zhafirin Your getter is, but your member variable is not. I'm not sure if that is the problem though

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your DB, it looks like you should use `int` or  `long` type instead of the `map` type, since your timestamp has a number value

Comment: just change it to long?

Comment: I did try change to everything from Map<String,String> to long. But it shows another error

Comment: this error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.Long

Comment: Have you changed all the references inside the class and used `Notes notes = noteSnapshot.getValue(Notes.class);`?