# How to use Firebase GenericTypeIndicator in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I can see that [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator) is from Firebase but I'm getting `Unresolved reference: GenericTypeIndicator`

Alternatively, I have a custom class

```
class Foo<T : Car> {
    ...
}
```

When I make a request to Firestore and want to convert `DocumentSnapshot` to my POJO, how exactly should I do? I'm getting `Could not deserialize object. Class Foo has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead`. Does that mean I have to do something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688361/1865027)?

Comment: Yes, GenericTypeIndicator is apart of Firebase Realtime Database Android SDK, so it cannot be used to get data from Firestore. If you need to get a "List" of custom objects, I think this article might help, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Comment: @AlexMamo but I have generic type. does that mean I'll need to create a new class for each type?